# Angular 6 JwtInterceptor

Tags: angular, jwt, angular6, interceptor

I am trying to implement a JWT interceptor using Angular 6. For some reason, the interceptor is not adding the Authorization header to my server requests. I have console logged in the JWTInterceptor provider class and everything, and it doesn't seem like the class is being called at all, even though I've added it to the Providers list in my AppModule. Basically, it seems like my interceptor is completely invisible, or that HTTP_INTERCEPTORS is not working.

./_helpers/jwt.interceptor.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from 
    '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

    @Injectable()
    export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
    Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // add authorization header with jwt token if available
    let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: { 
                Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`
            }
        });
    }

         return next.handle(request);
     }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform- 
browser/animations';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NounService } from './noun.service';
import { NojqueryComponent } from './nojquery.component'
import { AppRoutingModule }     from './app-routing.module';

import { FaderComponent } from './fader.component';

import {AngularMaterialModule} from './angular-material.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FaderComponent,
    NojqueryComponent

      ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AngularMaterialModule,

  ],
  providers: [
    NounService,
    { 
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, 
      useClass: JwtInterceptor, 
      multi: true 
    }

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My package.json angular dependencies

```
 "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^6.4.1",
"@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/material": "^6.4.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
```

My app.ts express header specs

```
  this.app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
     next();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the problem. For anyone who may be interested, this is the solution. In my service I was importing http from the http library, instead of the HttpClient module. So instead of importing like

```
import { http } from '@angular/http'
```

I need to do:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
```

And finally I needed to change my constructor parameter from:

```
constructor(){http: http}
```

to

```
constructor(){http: HttpClient}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide your **`JwtInterceptor`** in **`AppModule`**. First of all, import the **`HTTP_INTERCEPTORS`**:

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
```

... then provide **`JwtInterceptor`** in your module providers.

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    NounService,
    [{ 
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, 
        useClass: JwtInterceptor, 
        multi: true 
    }],
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I know this sounds really silly, but I do actually have the HTTP_INTERCEPTOR provider included in my appModule. I just forgot to add it here ! Thanks for the help nonetheless!

Comment: You should double check questions in future before posting :)